# Display text from file in a picture box

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to ask, how would you print text from a file directly into a pictureBox. Currently, my program is supposed to do that, but it fails, and I think the reason is, that I force the containerBox to the front of the program. The pictureboxes itself are black as of right now, but that is for testing purposes.

Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fileitems.Length; i++)
            {
                containerBox.Add(new PictureBox());
                //PictureBox pBox = new PictureBox();


                containerBox[i].Name = "cb" + i;
                containerBox[i].Location = new Point(Convert.ToInt32(b*0.05), curB);
                containerBox[i].Size = new Size(Convert.ToInt32(b*0.9),Convert.ToInt32(a/5));
                containerBox[i].BackColor = Color.Black;
                containerBox[i].Dock = DockStyle.Left;
                containerBox[i].Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
                //containerBox[i].Paint += PBox_Paint;

                j = containerBox[i].CreateGraphics();
                using (Font test1 = new Font("Arial", 14))
                {
                    j.DrawString(fileitems[i],test1,Brushes.Blue,new Point(2,2));
                }                    
                //this.Controls.Add(containerBox[i]);           
                //containerBox.Add(pBox);
                this.Controls.Add(containerBox[i]);
                containerBox[i].BringToFront();

                curB = Convert.ToInt32(containerBox[i].Location.Y+(a/5)+25);

            }
```

As you can see, I tried making it so, that I can paint, but then I can't access the file or read the data. Below you see the code in the paint event

Code:

```
private void PBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        /*
        using (Font test1 = new Font("Arial", 14))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString("test", test1, Brushes.Blue, new Point(3, 3));
        }*/
    }
```

How can I read the text from the file, then print it to the left side in the picturebox?

Comment: Since it's text, why not try to display the content in a control designed for that purpose?  Drawing text manually seems like the hardest way to go.

Comment: I am trying to create an picturebox ready for printing, since the final picturebox will be composed of several elements (text, a picture and a barcode), I thought this would be the best approach.